# What is the execution time of opencl related to?

Tags: c, arm, opencl

The time function that displays queue, submission, start, and end is as follows:

```c
void PrintProfilingInfo(cl_event event)
{
    cl_int err_num = -1;

    cl_ulong t_queued;
    cl_ulong t_submitted;
    cl_ulong t_started;
    cl_ulong t_ended;
    cl_ulong t_completed;

    err_num = clGetEventProfilingInfo(event, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_QUEUED,
                                      sizeof(cl_ulong), &t_queued, NULL);

    // submit time
    err_num = clGetEventProfilingInfo(event, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_SUBMIT,
                                      sizeof(cl_ulong), &t_submitted, NULL);

    // start time
    err_num = clGetEventProfilingInfo(event, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START,
                                      sizeof(cl_ulong), &t_started, NULL);

    // end time
    err_num = clGetEventProfilingInfo(event, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END,
                                      sizeof(cl_ulong), &t_ended, NULL);

    // complete time
    err_num = clGetEventProfilingInfo(event, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_COMPLETE,
                                      sizeof(cl_ulong), &t_completed, NULL);

    printf("queue  -> submit : %fus\n", (t_submitted - t_queued) * 1e-3);
    printf("submit -> start  : %fus\n", (t_started - t_submitted) * 1e-3);
    printf("start  -> end    : %fus\n", (t_ended - t_started) * 1e-3);
    printf("end    -> finish : %fus\n", (t_completed - t_ended) * 1e-3);
}
```

The function that displays the total execution time is as follows:

```c
timeval t_start;
long long time_diff;
timeval end;

gettimeofday(&t_start, NULL);

err_code = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(cl_cmd_queue,
                                    kernel,
                                    2,
                                    NULL,
                                    global_work_size,
                                    local_work_size,
                                    0,
                                    NULL,
                                    &kernel_event);
err_code = clWaitForEvents(1, &kernel_event);

gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
time_diff = 1000000 * (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec;
printf(" ==>> OpenCL Gaussian Blur average cost: %lld us\n", func_name, time_diff);
```

Here is the execution result:

[image]

My question is:

1. Why does the total execution time take so long?
2. Why sum of all the time on the device doesn't equal the total execution time? So, where is the main time spent on queue, submit, start, end, and complete?

I read the official documentation, and it doesn't seem to have a detailed explanation of what is done in the queue to submit time period.

Answer (score 0):

For kernels with small range, the main part of runtime might not be the kernel runtime itself but the PCIe data transfer. If you have a non-blocking CPU->GPU memory copy before the kernel call, that also gets measured with your clock. To avoid this, put a `clFinishQueue` before the start of the clock.

Non-blocking queue submits have basically instantaneous runtime. Only `clFinishQueue` and `clWaitForEvents`, which are blocking, tell you the runtime of queued PCIe copy and/or kernels.

The execution time of PCIe copy is `latency+capacity/bandwidth`, and the kernel execution time is `max((kernel arithmetic operations)/(Flops/s), (kernel VRAM transfer)/(VRAM bandwidth))`, see the [roofline model](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roofline_model).